# Обвертка в теге <a> PHP

Tags: php

есть переменная, которая содержит след. текст:

```
<a href="/some_link" some-tags="">Some text</a>
```

то есть `echo $text` выводит `<a href="/some_link" some-tags="">Some text</a>`

Так же, она может содержать и больше текста, например:

```
<a href="/some_link" some-tags="">Some text</a>
<a href="/some_link_2" some-tags="">Some text 2</a>
```

Нужно обвернуть текст внутри этих ссылкок в `<span>` средствами PHP
что бы получилось

```
<a href="/some_link" some-tags=""><span>Some text</span></a>
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C помощью регулярных, можно так:

```
$url= '<a href="/some_link_2" some-tags="">Some text 2</a>';

echo preg_replace('/<a(.+?)>(.+?)<\/a>/i', '<a$1><span>$2</span></a>', $url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
<?php
$text = '<a href="/some_link" some-tags="">Some text</a>';
echo explode('>', $text)[0].'><span>'.explode('>', explode('<', $text)[1])[1].'</span><'.explode('<', $text)[1];
?>
```

Comment: не не, видимо я не правильно вопрос задал, минуту

Comment: обновил вопрос )

Comment: @ВаняНизамов, но это конечно hard то что я написал, очень давно с php работал.. регулярные выражения не очень помню. Однако это один из вариантов.